# pandas: problems with merging dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge the two following dataframes `on=SICcode`:

```
df.head(5)

    SICcode     Catcode     Category                            SICname     MultSIC
0   111         A1500   Wheat, corn, soybeans and cash grain    Wheat        X
1   112         A1600   Other commodities (incl rice, peanuts)  Rice         X
2   115         A1500   Wheat, corn, soybeans and cash grain    Corn         X
3   116         A1500   Wheat, corn, soybeans and cash grain    Soybeans     X
4   119         A1500   Wheat, corn, soybeans and cash grain    Cash grains  X

df.columns.tolist()

['\ufeffSICcode', 'Catcode', 'Category', 'SICname', 'MultSIC']  

merged.head()


2012 NAICS Code     2002to2007 NAICS    SICcode
0   111110          111110               116
1   111120          111120               119
2   111130          111130               119
3   111140          111140               111
4   111150          111150               115

 merged.columns.tolist()
['2012 NAICS Code', '2002to2007 NAICS', 'SICcode']
```

When I try to merge them with the following code:

```
merged=pd.merge(merged,df, how='left', on='SICcode')
```

I get a `Keyerror: 'SICcode'`I tried to set the `dtype` of [One](https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/df.test) of the dfs but When I do, I receive a `Keycode error`.

If anyone has an idea on this or would request more information please let me know.

Comment: What's the code that's giving the error? `pd.merge(df, ef, on='SICcode')` should work unless you happen to have a space in the name.

Comment: Can you include the actual code which produces the error?

Comment: My apologies, I just updated the question reflecting the actual code.

Comment: I think it should be merged=ef.merge(df, how='left', on='SICcode')

Comment: @Sagar: I tried your suggestion and am getting the same error.

Comment: @MichaelPerdue, are you using/reading [this data](https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/df.test) for your DF? Could you also post `df.columns.tolist()` for both DFs?

Comment: @MaxU: Yes, this is one of the dfs that I am trying to merge. I provided the link because I think it has something weird with it.

Comment: Hi @MichaelPerdue it seems that the columns names are different, one of them probably contain a blank space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pay attention at the first column:

```
In [27]: df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/raw/master/df.test', index_col=0)

In [28]: df.columns.tolist()
Out[28]: ['\ufeffSICcode', 'Catcode', 'Category', 'SICname', 'MultSIC']

In [29]: df['SICcode']

...

KeyError: 'SICcode'

In [30]: df['\ufeffSICcode'].head()
Out[30]:
0    111
1    112
2    115
3    116
4    119
Name: SICcode, dtype: int64
```

as @unutbu has said in his comment, adding `encoding='utf-8_sig'` to the `pd.read_csv()` call might help you to fix this problem:

```
In [31]: df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/raw/master/df.test', index_col=0, encoding='utf-8_sig')

In [32]: df.columns.tolist()
Out[32]: ['SICcode', 'Catcode', 'Category', 'SICname', 'MultSIC']
```

Comment: @MaxU and unutbu: Problem Solved! Thank you both for pointing this out to me and offering a solution. I was reading the column names from the return on `.head()`. I had no idea that something like this could come up.